# Why do I get these 3 crazy errors in Android Media Player

Tags: java, android, android-mediaplayer

This is crazy, I get 3 errors when i click the play button once (the song doesn't play), But when i click the same play button again it starts playing. (On 2 click the songs play, after giving these 3 error). Where i am going wrong? Please help, Thank you :D

```
/* This are the errors which i get,
   start called in state 4
   error (-38, 0)
   Error (-38, 0)
*/

public class Jsonmedia extends Activity {
private MediaPlayer mp;
Button play;

public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.jsonview);

    mp = new MediaPlayer();
    mp.setAudioStreamType(AudioManager.STREAM_MUSIC);
    play = (Button) findViewById(R.id.play);

try{
//Logic that reads the file which is online, splits song_name and song_url in arrays

mp.setDataSource(song_url[0]); //read index zero of song_url;
}
//various catch statements

mp.prepareAsync();
    mp.setOnPreparedListener(new MediaPlayer.OnPreparedListener() {
        @Override
        public void onPrepared(MediaPlayer mp) {
            // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        }
    });

    play.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {

        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            // TODO Auto-generated method stub
            mp.start();
        }
    });

}

@Override
public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {
    // Inflate the menu; this adds items to the action bar if it is present.
    getMenuInflater().inflate(R.menu.jsonmedia, menu);
    return true;
}

}
```

errors

```
05-18 15:27:00.764: E/MediaPlayer(1593): start called in state 4
05-18 15:27:00.764: E/MediaPlayer(1593): error (-38, 0)
05-18 15:27:00.764: E/MediaPlayer(1593): Error (-38,0)
```

Comment: If you ask us about the errors you are getting, you should also post the exact error messages...

Comment: post ur logcat error msg

Comment: You need to call mp.start() in the onPrepared method

Comment: then it would auto start, which i don't want

Comment: @SagarPawar This error is thrown because your MediaPlayer isn't ready (the url is'nt loaded) the first time you click on the button, check the answer of user2340612 which seems to be a good solution.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Probably you click on start button before that the media player has prepared. You should do this way:

```
public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    ....
    play.setEnabled(false);


....

mp.setOnPreparedListener(new MediaPlayer.OnPreparedListener() {
    @Override
    public void onPrepared(MediaPlayer mp) {
        play.setEnabled(true);
    }
});
```

In this way you can click play button only when the player is ready

Comment: ;) keep in mind that it may take some time to get the button enabled because the audio stream comes from the internet.